# How do I load an rds file into R

Tags: r

I'm trying load a `rds` file which should contain some data.

Professor says to use `readRDS()`, however R gives this long error message which I've not been able to decipher myself.

I'm trying to load the file and place it in an Object.

I hope that someone are able to provide some clever solution to this problem.

```
Canteen_clean <- readRDS("C:/Users/a_s_j/OneDrive/Studie/Cand.merc.Business Intelligence/1. Semester/R for Business Analytics/.Rproj/39 - Graphics/Exercises02/canteen_clean.rds")
```

> Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message: In gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/a_s_j/OneDrive/Studie/Cand.merc.Business Intelligence/1. Semester/R for Business Analytics/.Rproj/39 - Graphics/Exercises02/canteen_clean.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

I'm using:
`pacman::p_load("pacman", "tidyverse")` to load the packages that should be necessary.

Comment: The important part of the error message is `'No such file or directory'`. That means the file is not in the location you named.

Comment: You can check if the file exists with `file.exists()`. You've most likely typed the file path wrong.

Comment: The `[...]/.Rproj/[...]` in your path looks suspicious to me, make sure your path is valid.

Comment: You can also use 'here' package to construct paths to your project's files. Read more: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/index.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Rather than typing a long file path, a really good idea in R is to let the system do the typing for you.  That is, do something like this:

```
 filename <- file.choose()
 Canteen_clean <- readRDS(filename)
```

The first line will open the usual file open dialog box; you can select the file you want, and the name will be stored in the `filename` variable.  The second line will use that name to open it.

Comment: This is a horrible suggestion. You should never be introducing forced user interaction in the middle of your code. No user wants to run an R script and suddenly be required to interact with the running script, let alone use mouse + GUI to make a selection. The OP's issue is related to their filepath, possibly a quirk of Windows paths or whitespace characters, etc. I'm sorry but this is a bad answer and I would hope that R users reading this will steer clear of this programming technique.

Comment: @user5359531:  I think you are misunderstanding the context.  This isn't a program written for others, this is a single user trying to read one file, and getting a file not found message.  The easiest way for that user to find the correct filename is to use `file.choose()`.

Comment: I understand the context. All code posted publicly online is code that others will end up using, and solutions posted on SO are going to find their way into other new programmers' code which others will end up having to use as well. As it stands, this question is one of the top Google results for "how to load an .Rds file". Fixing issues with OP's filepath handling are better for comments, making the "accepted solution"  `file.choose()` is a bad idea in this case.

Comment: @user5359531:  I understand your point, but you are wrong in applying it to this case.  The question has been edited (not by the author) since I posted my answer to remove some the context that this is a question from a beginner in R, but I think it is still the right answer for the asker.  If you know a better way to answer it, then you should post another answer.  But I think you are complaining that this isn't the answer to a different question.  You should ask that question, not complain about this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `setwd()`

reach to that folder location
then use

```
list.files()
```

to list all the files present in that folder

then use

```
t1 <- readRDS("/filename.rds")
head(t1)
```

to get that data.

Hope it solves your issue.

---------CODE---------------------------

```
> setwd(""C:/Users/a_s_j/OneDrive/Studie/Cand.merc.Business
> Intelligence/1. Semester/R for Business Analytics/.Rproj/39 -
> Graphics/Exercises02")
> 
> list.files()
> 
> t1 = readRDS("canteen_clean.rds") head(t1)
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try to use \\ instead of /. That is what works for me.

If this is not working there is a chance that the rds file is destroyed so you need either to recreate it or if you have access to get a new copy then try with a new copy.
I had the same issue once.

I hope that this helps

Comment: `/` is the correct way to do it. `\\\` works as well, but only on Windows, which is the only operating system using the backward slash for paths.