# "../" relative path directory not working R

Tags: r, directory, path, relative-path

I often have to work with shared data/code from Dropbox, and all of the files are usually loaded in as `df <- import("../data/branch/file_name.csv")`

However, this never loads on my computer, so I always have to type in my full directory as `df <- import("C:/Users/Name/Dropbox/Folder1/Folder2/data/branch/file_name.csv")`

Which makes it difficult for others to reproduce the code. Is there any way to fix this so that R can read the "../" part properly? I always get this error: Error: `path` does not exist: `../data/branch/file_name.csv`

(I used the import function as an example but this problem occurs with other packages or loading functions as well)

I've also tried using "~/" but the problem persists. The shared code I work with always uses "../" though so I'd prefer a solution that gets that to work instead so that I don't have to change the original script each time I need to use it.

Thank you very much.

Edit: Despite the conversation below, I am still having trouble with this. I tried setting the working directory and then using "../" and it sometimes works for `read_xls()` (it was working a few hours ago, not anymore, depsite doing the exact same thing and setting the same working directory) but not for `rio::import()` or other reading functions. I've even tried setting my working directory to the exact same folder and using "./" but no luck. Errors now say "Cannot open the connection" or "No such file"

Comment: It helps to know non-base packages you're using. The only reference to `imports` that I have is `backports::import` (which has nothing to do with CSV files). Unfortunately, I use "../" all the time, so it's not a generic R shortcoming. Are you verifying the current directory with `getwd()`?

Comment: This problem happens even if I use other packages such as readxl: `df <- read_xls("../data/file_name.xls")` I get the same error everytime. It just reads "../" as an error so I have to write out the full directory.

Comment: .... `getwd()`?

Comment: Does `dir.exists("..")` also produce an error?

Comment: Yes I get a TRUE when I run `dir.exists("..")`, @r2evans. I don't understand what you mean by getwd()? They match yes. But sometimes you need to upload files from other folders which will have different directories.. ?

Comment: R has its idea of what its "current working directory" is, and all operations must either be absolute (as you're resorting to using) or relative to that directory. (None of this is unique to R.) `getwd()` tells you what R thinks its current working directory is; if it is not what you expect it to be, then that is why your `"../data/....."` relative paths fail. You can change what R uses for its current directory using `setwd("new/path")`.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you! Yes when I do `setwd("..")` and then do `getwd()` I get the correct path I want. But it still doesn't work when I add the `../` before the rest of the file path. EDIT: ok nevermind, if I continue to run `setwd("..")` and `getwd()` multiple times, it just reduces the path until I'm left with `C:/` Not sure how to fix it

Comment: Sorry, 2nd update, since it reduces the path by 1 layer when I do `../`, I had to set the new path `setwd("new/path")` one layer ahead of the layer I want to upload. So the last layer is the same as the starting layer when I do `import("../path/file.csv")`. When I start R then, should I always be setting the working directory to that path before I upload data using "../" then? (I had no idea people did this.. I just thought they opened the file and ran it..)

Comment: If you're using RStudio, it has the concept of "Projects" that reside in a particular directory. That isn't necessarily a directory with R script files, in fact I think that's not necessarily the best project organization. If a project is rooted on (say) `C:/Users/me/Projects/ABC`, then one might have `R/` with scripts, `data/` with CSV and other data files, perhaps `output/` with rendered PDFs. In that context, then one might `source("R/somecode.R")` and `dat <- read.csv("data/somedata.csv")`.

Comment: My intent was not that you `setwd("..")` repeatedly until you get to the `C:/` directory. It was so that you clearly identify (1) where `"../data/file_name.xls")` is *relative to* (such as an R directory or something else), and the `setwd(...)` to *that* directory so that `"../data/"` will correctly point to the directory you're referencing. Some perhaps-helpful links for proj org: https://martinctc.github.io/blog/rstudio-projects-and-working-directories-a-beginner%27s-guide/ and https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200526207-Using-Projects.

Comment: And lastly (for now), depending on the scope and expected lifetime of the project/code, many recommend organizing the project as an R package. For some people, it is always "hard and/or not right". For some projects, it might be overkill. (Some projects really suggest *multiple* packages.)

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but an alternative approach:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59108817/2554330

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting your working directory(wd) to the current folder first, then use read.csv to import the data.

1. To set the working directory, first obtain the current directory using `rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path` then use `setwd()` to set the wd to this path.
2. Then use whatever function to import your data.

For example, let's say your R code is saved in the "branch" folder, then the following code should work just fine:

```
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
mydata <- read.csv("./file_name.csv")
head(mydata)
```

Otherwise, if your R code was saved in a subfolder under `Folder2` called `code` such that your R script's directory is: `"C:/Users/Name/Dropbox/Folder1/Folder2/code/mycode.R"`, then the following should work:

```
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
mydata <- read.csv("../data/branch/file_name.csv")
head(mydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the person you are collaborating with has their working directory set to a separate folder within Folder2 (perhaps a folder with all the .R code?). The `..` means that the relative path is referencing the next folder up from the working directory (the next folder up is presumably Folder2).

To solve your problem, every time you start working you need to set your working directory to the same folder that your collaborator is using for their working directory. For example, this may be something like `setwd("C:/Users/Name/Dropbox/Folder1/Folder2/RCode")`. Unfortunately you will have to do that every time you open up the script, but if you do it at the very beginning, then the rest of the code should work.

Working directories can be hard to manage, especially when collaborating. A better solution to the working directory problem is to create a [project](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/workflow-projects.html) in R Studio and collaborate on that project using GitHub. If you don't have experience with GitHub, [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZF9C0YMKuns9sLDzK6zoiV) are an approachable resource for helping you get started.